# Data structure to store client data retrieved from a Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, data-structures, dictionary

In a web application I invoke a web service to get metadata of documents related to a specific client. This call might return a set of document records between 10 and 300. 
I would like to store the retrieved data in a Dictionary (Key = docID - Value = metadata as complex class) and check first for the document ID into the Dictionary. Only if not found, then I would call the web service (and update then the dictionary).

**How could I maintain that data structure within the users session?** 
Different users can access the application and request data about different (or same) clients. There will be max 40 users connected in the same moment.

**How safe/performant would be to create a singleton class to manage this data structure?** Moreover avoiding it will grow too much.

Does anyone know a good practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) to store the `Dictionary`.  The `Cache` is application-wide shared across all `Sessions`.

```
if(Cache["Documents"] != null){
    var dict = (Dictionary<int,YourClass>)Cache["Documents"];
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(documentID)){
        dict.Add(documentID, yourComplexClass);
    }
}else{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int,YourClass>();
    dict.Add(documentID, yourComplexClass);
    Cache.Insert("Documents", dict);
}
```

Comment: ok - I think the OP needs to be very clear what they are doing when chooseing between Cache and Session :)

Comment: +1 Tim, that's sure a good point. I will look more in detail to cache since I did not work with it before. Are concurrent access already provided or do I have to design that? Moreover what would be the best approach to limit/clean the cache?

Comment: @Luca: That depends on the lifetime of your data and whether it can be changing from "outside" of this web-application or not. You don't necessarily need to clean the cache although it's possible to provide dependencies and expiration policies. You could create your singleton class that controls this cache-item and provides Getter/Setter.

Comment: Information related to existing documents rarely changes in the remote archive (where the data is retrieved via web service). This happens when a document has been replaced by a newer version of the same. Unfortunately this happens completely asynchronously from my application, therefore I have no way to know when this happens and clear the cache. A compromise could be setting the expiration time to 2 or 3 days. Moreover I have read it is preferred save more simple info (as example, the documentID GUID) into the cache, rather than fewer complex data, as a Dictionary. Do you also agree on that?

Comment: You could use a [HostFileChangeMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.hostfilechangemonitor.aspx) to monitor the archive directory, can't you? Have a look at the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235.aspx). On this way the cache would automatically updated on changes. If you don't have access to this directory, a expiration time would be the simplest.  Where have you read this? A Dictionary can store anything as value. As key i woulds also recommend the document-guid.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the dictionary in session.

not sure where a singleton would come into this - just use the session manager.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: Any object can be stored in the Session even if it's not serializable. Don't mix it with Viewstate.

Comment: well it is true when session is stored in memory. However it is possible to store in elsewherу (SQL Server or ASP.NET state service)

Comment: good point - I was confusing it with a customised scenario I had where session had to be serialized for failover purposes.

Comment: What would be about performance side? For each client call a set up to 300 documents might be returned and each user tipically requests data about 10 to 30 different clients in a day.

Comment: If the data can be shared then you need Cache as mentioned by tim, if it is private to the user then you need session.

Comment: Thanks dice. The metadata requested by the users would be exactly the same if related to the same client. Therefore it would make sense share data for the same client between different users.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to store that dictionary in [Application store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx), not user session.